# onKey method in turtle module

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I copied the following code from my textbook but it will not run. I get the error "builtins.AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkey'". I know that the onkey is a methon with the turtle module because it states that it is on the python website. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import turtle
class Etch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myT = turtle.Turtle()
        self.myT.color('blue')
        self.myT.pensize(2)
        self.myT.speed(0)
        self.distance = 5
        self.turn = 10

        self.myT.onkey(self.fwd,'Up')
        self.myT.onkey(self.bkwd,'Down')
        self.myT.onkey(self.left,'Left')
        self.myT.onkey(self.right,'Right')
        self.myT.onkey(self.quit,'q')
        self.myT.listen()

    def fwd(self):
        self.myT.forward(self.distance)

    def bkwd(self):
        self.myT.backward(self.distance)

    def left(self):
        self.myT.left(self.turn)

    def right(self):
        self.myT.right(self.turn)

    def quit(self):
        self.myT.bye()

    def main(self):
        cTurtle.mainloop()

draw = Etch()
draw.main()
```

Full traceback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/cshome/nbrost/Downloads/etch.py", line 36, in 
    draw = Etch()
    File "/cshome/nbrost/Downloads/etch.py", line 11, in **init**
    self.myT.onKey(self.fwd,'Up')
    builtins.AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'onkey'

Comment: Full traceback please. Also fix indentation?

Comment: Sorry the indentation was messed up when I copied from editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some turtle methods belong to Turtle, some belong to Screen.  For beginners, the turtle module tries to hide this distinction.  But, for more sophisticated usage, like class methods, it's easy to trip over.  I've revised your class to have a Screen member which is used on screen-related methods:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Etch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myT = Turtle()
        self.myT.color('blue')
        self.myT.pensize(2)
        self.myT.speed(0)
        self.distance = 5
        self.turn = 10

        self.myS = Screen()
        self.myS.onkey(self.fwd,'Up')
        self.myS.onkey(self.bkwd,'Down')
        self.myS.onkey(self.left,'Left')
        self.myS.onkey(self.right,'Right')
        self.myS.onkey(self.quit,'q')
        self.myS.listen()

    def fwd(self):
        self.myT.forward(self.distance)

    def bkwd(self):
        self.myT.backward(self.distance)

    def left(self):
        self.myT.left(self.turn)

    def right(self):
        self.myT.right(self.turn)

    def quit(self):
        self.myS.bye()

    def main(self):
        self.myS.mainloop()

draw = Etch()
draw.main()
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks. I thought it must have something to do with screen. I've used other modules that require methods being used on the screen/window.